# Why can't I load ubuntu.com over wifi connection?

Tags: wireless

This is bizarre.  I am unable to load ubuntu.com on either of two wifi-connected computers (one is Ubuntu 12.04, the other is a Win8.1 laptop).  It does load on an ethernet-connected Windows box, and a 4G-connected Android phone.  (But not when the phone is using the wifi connection.)  What could be causing this?

Other sites seem to be loading fine on the wifi-connected computers.  Any help/suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting (timeout , DNS)? Can you ping ubuntu.com?

Comment: Timeout error, pinging works fine (tried from both).  I notice on the laptop that Chrome will sometimes say it is waiting for "assets.ubuntu.com" (if it gets that far).  Not sure if this even exists -- downforeveryoneorjustme.com keeps telling me this site is "down".

Comment: Hm, I thought it was timeout, but Chrome gives me "Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".  Which, given that this is happening on two different computers with different OS, makes me worry about the router.  Which is unpleasant.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the DNS on your router? assets.ubuntu.com either doesn't exist or is down. It gives me a 404 page and DFEOJM says it is down. The IP I have for ubuntu.com is: `~$ host ubuntu.com  
ubuntu.com has address 91.189.94.156` This address works, I can get to ubuntu.com.

Comment: Hm...  No, assets.ubuntu.com is real & working.  I can ping it, it's just that the fp is restricted (403), which apparently equates to "down" at DFEOJM.  The fp at www.ubuntu.com draws a bunch of resources from there (images, js), but if I type in the address of one of the images, it shows up on my browser.  Not sure what 'asset' the browser is choking on.

Comment: So, I thought about answering, but unless someone can plumb the bowels of my ISP, I think calling this an "answer" is presumptuous.  Long story short, I think the page loading on the ethernet connection was a huge fluke, because it failed to do so later.  So I'm thinking it was just an ISP thing, because it has by magic resolved itself everywhere, as of late yesterday.  Thanks to Louis Matthijssen and dash-plus-java for taking the time to comment.